# Why can't Update set change data type Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a CSV which contains numbers stored as strings example: 1,200 when loading in these are stored as `VARCHAR`

I'd like to store these as integers. So tested the below;

```sql
update data
set stringy_number = replace (stringy_number,',','')::integer
```

This runs and removes the `,` from the number but doesn't change the character type. I then tried;

```sql
update data
set stringy_number::integer = replace (stringy_number,',','')::integer
```

Which threw a syntax error. At which point I switched to the below which worked, but I don't understand why I can't set a data type along with an update

```sql
alter table data
alter column stringy_number type integer using replace(stringy_number,',','')::integer;
```

Answer (score 0):

`update` works on the values. You can cast from a datatype to another, but the result is still cast to to underlying column type.

--> you can save a "number" in a text column because it is easy to cast a number to a text. You cannot save a letter in a numerical column because the cast cannot (easily) be done.

`alter column` works on the entire column type. When changing the type, you can supply a custom transformation method allowing the old data to match the new data type.